# InnerHTML и iframe

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Пример кода iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://hashcode.ru/"></iframe>
```

Т.е. не указывается ни ID, ни CLASS, ни т.д., ни т.п. На странице несколько iframe. Нужный нам - второй по счёту.

Как я пытался его заменить:

```
var theElement = window.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var txt_zamena = "Test_txt";
theElement[1].innerHTML = txt_zamena;
```

Прошу помочь.

Comment: А какая разница - есть id или class, толи их нет? Если бы вы посмотрели ошибку, которую выдает отладчик, то без труда бы заметили, что-то вроде этого "**Permission denied to access...**". И уже вопрос бы ваш строился по другому. Доступ к документу другого домена, загруженному во фрейме, ограничен из-за нарушения концепции [правила ограничения домена](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)/политикой безопасности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно сам фрейм заменить на что-либо:

```
var elements = window.frames;
var text = "Test_txt";
elements[1].parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(text), elements[1]);
```

Если нужно заменить страницу, которая открывается во фрейме:

```
var elements = window.frames;
elements[1].src = 'http://ya.ru';
```

Если нужно редактировать страницу во фрейме, смотрите комментарий Deonis'a. Доступ к странице в фрейме можно получить только в пределах одного домена (страница во фрейме и страница, содержащая фрейм, должны быть на одном сайте). Тогда можно сделать так:

```
var elements = window.frames;
var text = "Test_txt";
elements[1].document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мне нужно было заменить сам фрейм. Правда пришлось немного изменить код - вместо window.frames использовал window.document.getElementsByTagName (т.к. с window.frames не работало).